# One-to-one or zero relationship in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I read some articles and answers, but nothing helped.

I have two entites:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class ProductType : IEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Article { get; set; }

    //.....
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Product
{
    [Key]   
    [DataMember]
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("ProductType")]
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

ProductTypeId column in table is primary key. And I want to have One-to-one or zero relationship here. But I can't do like this:

```
// Configure the primary key for the OfficeAssignment
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasKey(t => t.ProductTypeId);

// Map one-to-zero or one relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.ProductType)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Product);
```

Because I haven't Product property in ProductType entity.

I tried this, but ProductType property is null:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("ProductType")]
        [DataMember]
        public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in missed *virtual* keyword.

Such code works for me:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("ProductType")]
        [DataMember]
        public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```